# How to force font change on Chrome (Chromium) on certain websites (viz. Facebook)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, chromium, css

Since I started using Google Chrome (and Chromium) on Ubuntu, I had this bad feeling about changing Facebook font (or FORCING the font change in Settings on certain websites that have their own CSS).

I have spent about 3 years now asking and googling the web how to force font change on Chrome (Chromium) on certain websites, and in my case Facebook?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) from Chrome's Web Store. It works for both Chrome and Chromium.

Then, make a "style" for urls on the domain "facebook.com". Just this code gives the image shown below:

```
*  { font-family: "Comic Sans MS" !important; color: red !important; }
```

[image: Red-lettered Facebook]

Users of Stylish can visit userstyles.org for skins and themes or forum.userstyles.org for advice.